# C# checking for Null when a class has operator overloads

Tags: c#

My .NET Framework v4.5.2 app is throwing a `NullReferenceException` on the following line:

```
if (CurrentZip.Container.Exists)
```

I want to write a check around this to make sure that `CurrentZip.Container` is not null, however there are existing operator overloads for the type of `Container` which is called `RichFileInfo` (not written by me):

```
    public static bool operator ==(RichFileInfo x, RichFileInfo y)
    {
        return String.Equals(x.FullName, y.FullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(RichFileInfo x, RichFileInfo y)
    {
        return !String.Equals(x.FullName, y.FullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

So, even checking `CurrentZip.Container != null` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

How do I safely check for null in this case of there being an operator overload?

Answer (score 2):

maybe just do `if(CurrentZip.Container is null && CurrentZip.Container.Exists)`?

here's from the Microsoft docs:

> **When you match an expression (is) against null, the compiler guarantees
> that no user-overloaded == or != operator is invoked.** Beginning with
> C# 11, you can use is null on unconstrained generic types.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is

Comment: "When you match an expression (is) against null, the compiler guarantees that no user-overloaded == or != operator is invoked.", Nice! I feel like `is` is much nicer to read.

Comment: In order to use this, make sure you target C# 7 or above.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.ReferenceEquals(objectA, objectB)` should accomplish what you need (if the other answer didn't already solve your issue). It can't be overridden so it should always work the same, and evaluates to a `bool` so it can be used in the same manner as your other checks.

See Microsoft's documentation on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Object_ReferenceEquals_System_Object_System_Object_).

To be clear, you would want to implement it like so to compare against null:

```
//invert
if(!Object.ReferenceEquals(CurrentZip.Container, null)) 
{
    // is not equal to null
    
}
```